# How can I discover what JavaScript function is called when clicking on something on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I'm trying to deconstruct part of Gmail and can't seem to be able to find what is happening (what functions are called) when a specific button is clicked.

I used Google Chrome's inspector and found the HTML for the button:

```
<tbody id=":8y" class="vC " idlink="" role="option" aria-labelledby=":8x :8w"><tr class="vI"><td><img class="vt SFzvCe IRnhDe BUw1sf" id=":8x" src="images/cleardot.gif" alt="Call phone"></td><td id=":8v" class="vr" colspan="2"><span id=":8w" class="HHshnc ">Call phone</span></td></tr></tbody>
```

In the "Event Listeners" section of the inspector under "click" I got this information:

```
isAttribute: false
lineNumber: 213
listenerBody: function B(H){return g.call(B.src,B.key,H)}
node: tbody#:8y
sourceName: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&view=js&name=main,tlist&ver=q0qiADndhKA.en.&am=!k3sV9...
type: click
useCapture: true
```

but that doesn't help me understand what's being called onClick.

What I'm trying to do is create a Greasemonkey script that will add this button to Gmail when it doesn't exist on a page.

TIA!

Comment: What does "function B(H){return g.call(B.src,B.key,H)}" do then?

Comment: Not sure, but that's not the call to the function in any case (it's the function itself).
I'm trying to recreate the button so I'd need something like onClick="B(something)" which calls that function (I assume). 
I haven't been able to find any information on what listenerBody means.

Comment: Methinks listenerBody *is* the function that is called when the button is clicked. Good luck with `B.key` there, I'm pretty sure it's unique per user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function B(H){return g.call(B.src,B.key,H)}
```

is clearly only a wrapper function that calls `g`. [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

> [c]alls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually.

As you can read on the linked MDC page, the first argument is the `this` object inside `g`, in this case `B.src`. The second and third parameter are passed as parameters to `g`.

So, you'll have to look for a function named `g`. The [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) method might be helpful.

That said, given the goal you're trying to reach (“create a Greasemonkey script that will add this button to Gmail when it doesn't exist on a page”), I think it's not worth your time. If the button doesn't exist, I suspect it doesn't exist for a reason (e.g., `g` not being available on that page, or some other back-end function).

Comment: Not quite sure I understood what you meant with toString.


I'm pretty sure it will work. The reason the button is not on the page is because the functionality is not available in some countries. I had a browser window open with the functionality before leaving the country and when I landed the button continued to work (in the country where it's not available).

Comment: @Guy – Did you follow [the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) (I know it can be hard to see it is a link)? Just call something like `g.toString()` in your console and you'll see `g`'s contents. You can then use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to reformat the function.